# CakePHP 3: change order in dateWidget

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I found on [the CakePHP developer's guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#datetime-options) the following hint on how to adjust the order of the fields when using the `date` form input. It says

> To control the order of inputs, and any elements/content between the inputs you can override the dateWidget template.

However, I cannot find anywhere a hint on how to change the order and use this in a view. Can you give hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the DateWidget template when initializing the Form helper

```
// in MyController.initialize()
$this->loadHelper('Form', [
    'dateWidget' => '{{year}}{{month}}{{day}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}'
]);
```

or you can override the template using the `templates` function in the form component

```
$this->Form->templates([
    'dateWidget' => '{{year}}{{month}}{{day}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}'
]);
```

@see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference... this seems to work as well placed directly in the view:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('date_of_birth',               
    [ 
    'templates' => [ 
        'dateWidget' => '<div class="clearfix">{{month}}<span class="spacer-date">/</span>{{day}}<span class="spacer-date">/</span>{{year}}</div>',
    ],
    'type' => 'date',
    'label' => 'Date of Birth',
    'empty' => array(
        'month' => '(month)',
        'day'   => '(day)',
        'year'  => '(year)'
    ),
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18
    ]
) ?>
```