# CakePHP 3.5.3 set default date(Time)

Tags: date, datetime, cakephp, datepicker, datetimepicker

I want to set the default date(Time) of CakePHP, such that I can create a date control/datepicker in my view, which automatically displays in the wanted format 'dd-MM-yyyy'.

Somehow the format shown, keeps being 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

In my view file I created the date control/datepicker by:

```
echo $this->Form->input('startdate', ['type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Van', 'monthNames' => false, 'dateFormat' =>  'dd-MM-yyyy', 'minYear' => '2017']);
```

I configured the defaultLocale in config/app.php & config/app.default.php.

```
//
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'nl_NL'),
//
```

And in config/bootstrap.php I set the defaultLocale.

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', Configure::read('App.defaultLocale'));
```

Besides that I set the the timezone in config/bootstrap.php.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```

Enabling default locale format parsing in the same file also didn't have any effect.

```
Type::build('time')
 ->useImmutable();
Type::build('date')
 ->useLocaleParser()
 ->setLocaleFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
Type::build('datetime')
 ->useLocaleParser()
 ->setLocaleFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Neither did changing it at runtime:

```
Time::setDefaultLocale('nl-NL'); // For any mutable DateTime
FrozenTime::setDefaultLocale('nl-NL'); // For any immutable DateTime
Date::setDefaultLocale('nl-NL'); // For any mutable Date
FrozenDate::setDefaultLocale('nl-NL'); // For any immutable Date

Time::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
FrozenTime::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
Date::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Comment: There is no `dateFormat` option AFAIK, it sounds like you want to change the dropdown order? In that case: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876688/cakephp-3-change-order-in-datewidget**

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Much appreciated.